# A value cannot be stored to my custom field in type Task

Tags: apex, custom-field, error-messages

I've created a custom field of type DateTime in Task object.

I try to add to my custom field an object from type DateTime.

But I receive the following error message:

> **A value cannot be stored to my_custom_field in type Task**

Here is the code:

```
Datetime now = Datetime.now();
Integer offset = UserInfo.getTimezone().getOffset(now);
Datetime localTime = now.addSeconds(offset/1000);
DateTime realEndTime = localTime;
task.Scheduled_Timeframe__c = realEndTime;
```

Do you know how to solve and avoid this error?

Comment: Please share your actual code... Also did you add any validation rules?

Comment: I have edited and updated my question with the actual code the way you requested.

Comment: You need to set the field on a record, not the object definition itself. Are you trying to update one or create a new one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an instance of `Task`, make sure variable should not be reserved word.

It will like this:

```
Task tsk = new Task();

Datetime now = Datetime.now();
Integer offset = UserInfo.getTimezone().getOffset(now);
Datetime localTime = now.addSeconds(offset/1000);
DateTime realEndTime = localTime;
tsk.Scheduled_Timeframe__c = realEndTime;
```